# Git - if I delete a commit from a parent branch, will it also disappear from child branch that was created while commit was on the parent branch?

Tags: git

I have added a feature on a parent branch. It has been committed and pushed to origin.
It has since been decided to not implement this feature just yet.
So I want to delete the commit but to save the work for future.
How should I do it?

I am thinking of creating a child branch from the parent branch so it will contain the commit and then delete the commit from the parent branch.

But if I delete the commit from the parent branch, will it also disappear from the child branch?

Comment: As far as I’m aware have little to no impact on each other. Remember, a branch is only a label for a commit. If you have two branches with the same commits, delete a commit from one branch (by rebasing for example) the deleted commit will still be on the other branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You literally can't *delete* the commit—not directly, anyway.  So I suppose the answer is "no", sort of.  But you can *forget* the commit.  That makes the answer more complicated.

Branches do not have parent/child relationships, either.  *Commits* have parent/child relationships.

The way this works is actually very simple:

- Each Git commit has a unique hash ID.  That hash ID—a big ugly string of letters and digits, which you'll see in `git log` output for instance—is in effect the true name of the commit.  It's how Git finds the commit.
- Each Git commit stores two things: its main data, which is a snapshot of all of your files, and some metadata: information about the commit, such as who made it, when, and why (your log message).  In that metadata, Git includes the hash ID of the commit's *parent* commit.

This means that each commit points *backwards* to its predecessor.  If you have a series of commits, with big ugly hash IDs, in a sequence, we can draw them like this if we let uppercase letters stand in for the actual hash IDs:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` is the *latest* commit.  It contains, as part of its metadata, the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  So Git can extract `G` from the repository, using the metadata part of `H`.  Of course, `G` contains the hash ID of earlier commit `F`, and so on.

So now, we add one more bullet point:

- A *branch name* holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.

That is, if we get a little lazy about drawing the internal arrows—which all point backwards—we can draw this as:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

The *name* `master` holds the hash ID of commit `H`, so master *points to* `H`.  The metadata of commit `H` holds the hash ID of commit `G`, so `H` *points to* `G`.  `G` points to `F`, which points on back still earlier.

If you have more than one branch name, the two branch names can both point to the *same* commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, br1
```

or they can point to *different* commits:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- br1
```

It's the *commits* that really matter here.  Branch names just let us—and Git—*find* the commits.

When you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to select a branch by name, Git:

- extracts the commit's frozen-for-all-time files into a work area, so that you can see and work on them
- attaches the special name `HEAD` to the branch name, so that Git can find both the current *branch* (the name `HEAD` is attached to) and the current *commit* (the commit that the name points-to).

We can draw that like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- br1
```

or:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

In one drawing, the current branch is `master` and the current commit is `H`; in the other, the current branch is `br1` and the current commit is `I`.

To make a *new* commit, Git:

- writes out the snapshot (using Git's *index*, which we won't cover here);
- sets the new commit's metadata, using:

  - your name and email address, from your `git config user.name` and so on;
  - "now" as the date-and-time-stamp;
  - your log message;
  - the *current commit* hash ID as the parent of the new commit; and
- last, now that the new commit exists, writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name.

So if we're on commit `I` via name `br1`, and we make a new commit `J`, we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

All you can ever do this way is *add* commits.

You can add new branch names any time you like.  This has no effect on the commits themselves, though we might need more lines to draw the graph here as plain text.  For instance, given the above, we can add a `brexit` branch name pointing to commit `I`:

```
git branch brexit br1~1
```

which produces:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- brexit
              \
               J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

We can also *delete* branch names at any time, e.g., `git branch -d brexit`.  This has no effect on the commits themselves:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
              \
               J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

It's just that the *name* that finds commit `I` directly is now gone.  We can still find commit `I`: we just start at `J` and work backwards.  (And we can shrink the drawing to use fewer lines, if we like.)

Branch names are, in effect, just labels that *point to* one specific commit, each.  You can have many names for a commit, or a commit with no names at all.  **These branch names have one special property**: you can attach `HEAD` to them, and make new commits, and the branch names move along with you as you make the new commits.

#### "Undoing" a commit: `git revert` adds a commit

If you use `git revert` to back out a commit, Git just adds a new commit that undoes the effect of the previous commit.  For instance, if you run:

```
git revert <hash-of-I>
```

while we're in the above state, we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

where commit `K` is just a commit that backs-out whatever we did in commit `I`.

There is a pattern here, and it boils down to another very simple rule: *nothing can change any existing commit*.

#### "Undoing a commit": we can *forget* commits with `git reset`

What if we had a command that could reach in and yank a label off some existing commit and paste it onto some other commit?  Suppose, for instance, we decide to make the name `br1` point to commit `J` again.  Here's what that might look like:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
                 \
                  K   ???
```

As before, we had to move commit `K` to draw this.  It's still there, but there's a really important question: **How can we find commit `K`?**

The answer is: we can't!  It's lost.  If we saved its hash ID somewhere—if we wrote it down on a scrap of paper, for instance—we could get it that way.  But if we've forgotten the hash ID, it's really hard to find.

There is a command that does exactly this: `git reset`.  (Actually, there are multiple commands that can move branch names, but we'll stick with `git reset` here.)  If we run:

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-J>
```

Git will move the name back one step, in the direction the internal arrows go, but opposite the normal direction for branch growth.  Git will save commit `K`'s hash ID somewhere, in case we want it back, and keep it around for a while, but the saved hash ID doesn't show up in normal everyday Git commands and you won't *see* commit `K` any more.  It *seems* to be gone.

> Aside: You might wonder why this is `git reset --hard`.  That has to do with the index, which we aren't going into, and your work-tree.  The `git reset` command is complicated!  It has multiple modes, some of which do more than others.  The `--hard` part tells Git: *reset my work-tree too*.  Your work-tree is not really part of the Git repository.  The files you see here, and edit to work with them, are *yours* and Git won't normally overwrite them, or remove them, unless you tell it to do so; but `git reset --hard` means *overwrite my files*.
>
> Since these files *aren't* in the repository, Git can't get them back after overwriting them.  So be very careful with `git reset --hard`.  If you have done a `git add` and `git commit`, the *commit* holds *snapshots* of the files.  Those snapshots *are* in Git and are read-only and saved forever, or at least, for as long as you can find the commit.  So those copies are safe.  It's your work-tree copies that are just temporary, and can be wiped out easily.

When you do reset a commit away, so that you can't find it, Git will eventually forget the hash ID itself.  By default, the log entry that saves the hash ID is erased after 30 days.  Once that happens, *Git* can delete the commit entirely.

#### The key is *reachability*

The real key here, to whether a commit remains forever or is eventually deleted, is something called *reachability*.  For much more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), but in a nutshell, consider this state:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
              \
               K--L   <-- br2
```

Lots of people would call `br2` a "child branch" of `br1`, but Git doesn't think that way.  Git thinks, instead, `br2` points to `L`, and therefore all the commits up to and including `L` are *reachable* from `br2`.  Git will start at `L` and work backwards: `K`, `J`, `I`, `H`, `G`, and so on.

Meanwhile, by starting from `br1`, all commits up through `J` are reachable: Git starts at `J`, then goes back to `I` and so on.  By starting from `master`, all commits up through `H` are reachable.  **Note that commits up through `H` are on all three branches** and commits up through `J` are on two.

If we now use `git reset --hard` to move `br1` back one step, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
           \
            J--K--L   <-- br2
```

That is, commit `J` is still there, and still reachable—but now it's only on `br1`.

#### Conclusion

That's the big difference between revert and reset: `git revert` *adds a new commit*, while `git reset` lets you *move a branch name around* (and with `--hard`, clobbers your work-tree files).  With `revert`, the original commits are definitely still around; with `reset`, whether you can find any commits you have reset away, depends on what other names are still around to find commits, and the links between the commits.

As [michid answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61486865/1256452), you probably *don't* want to use `git reset` here, because you have done a `git push` already.  This took the new commit you made with `git commit` and handed it off to some *other* Git repository.  They will retain your commit: Gits do not "like" to forget commits.  To get *them* to forget your commit is harder, and usually not a good idea—though *how* hard depends on how widespread that commit got in the meantime.

Since revert *adds* a commit, and Gits are greedy and will add new commits as fast as they see them, it's easy to get the other Git to *add* an "undo" style commit.

Comment: If as you said, a branch is just a label; Is it a label for a commit, or for a set of commits?

Comment: If it is for only one commit then how can commits be on one branch (and navigable only on it) and not on another.

Comment: "where commit K is just a commit that backs-out whatever we did in commit I". Shouldn't it instead say that K backs out J?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but I still do not get your explanation of branches. You have drawn all the commits on a bent line. They are linear, not branching out. If I am at commit I and do a `git checkout -b M` then will that create a true branch like in a tree?

Comment: over here, branch `bar` is a set of commits `D, E`. http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/using-git-cherry-pick-to-simulate-git-rebase.html

Comment: @likejudo: the name holds just the one commit's hash ID. The set of commits that is *reachable from* that one commit is determined by looking through the commits. That is, we use the name once, to look up a single commit. Then we throw the name away and use the commits to look up commits. If we *keep* the name instead of throwing it away, we can claim that all those commits are "on" the branch. If we throw the name out after doing the lookup, then the name only means the one commit.

Comment: The problem with keeping the name while looking up many commits, then claiming "this name represents this set of commits", is that the name's value may *change* while we're looking up the large set of commits. This happens all the time in server repositories, for instance. Nonetheless, we often say "these commits are on this branch" *anyway*, and rely on the names not to have changed, or the person we're talking to to understand that this condition is temporary.

Comment: As for the revert: no, we ran `git revert <hash-of-I>`. So new commit `K` has the effect of backing out the snapshot-style work we did going from `H` to `I`, not the work we did going from `I` to `J`.

Comment: Last, if you create a new branch named `M` that identifies commit `I`, all you have at this point is a name `M` identifying existing commit `I`. To make this into a new "branch-like structure", you can now create a new commit (call it `N` or `O` perhaps, since `M` is the branch name) which will update the name `M` to point to the new commit. The new commit's parent will be `I`, since the name `M` used to name commit `I`.

Comment: This is a really excellent ELI5 explanation on git! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "delete the commit" I assume you mean you revert the commit with `git revert`. This will add a new commit to the current branch, which essentially undos everything from the previous commit. Any other branch containing the reverted commit will not be affected by this. So in your case the commit in question will not disappear from the child branch.

Comment: I did not know about `git revert`. Should I use revert or `git reset`? And should I do anything at the remote origin?

Comment: Use `git revert HEAD` to revert the latest commit. This will generate a commit message for you stating that this commit reverts the previous one. Afterwards `git push` to the remote origin.

Comment: Don't use `git reset` for this as you would not be able to push the changed history to the remote origin (unless you use force, which creates troubles for everybody else working on the same code).